# Ways to analyze unknown USB device?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, tcp

I have a piece of equipment at work that has a USB output, that then requires to be connected to a specific USB-to-Ethernet adapter in order to send TCP packets. I am trying to cut the Ethernet adapter out of the equation, and connect the USB output directly to the computer.

A Windows machine does not detect hardware changes when it's connected, so I'm thinking about using a Ubuntu device since it might have better network tools.

What are the ways I can test the device to figure out what it actually is? Is it even possible to remove the adapter from the equation in this situation?

PS. The device is a very specific ECU used in cars. It is not something I can download drivers for. It also uses a Class C IP address.

Comment: Unless you really want to do some low-level access to the device, this question is not about programming. If I were you, I'd google for `usbmon` and `vusb-analyzer`.

Comment: I don't mind doing coding.